# Issues reading button state in the serial monitor

Tags: arduino

i'm having some issues whit a little program in arduino with a button; i have a code that i make a little modified from the examples of the arduino's page.

the code is

```
const int buttonPin = 7;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Serial.println(buttonState);
}
```

Probably you will follow the simple idea, the program read the state of the button and send to the serial the value of the state. 
The idea is, it will send something like

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

when the button is not pressed
and

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

when it is.

but i recieve something like this when it's not pressed

```
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
```

... i had this problems with other type of inputs but i just want tu figured it out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what you explain, you connected the button to 5V. Then, when you press the button you are connecting the input to logical level 1. But when you release the button, Arduin's input is connected to nowhere. Which isn't 1 nor 0 logic level. That's why you get an ambiguous reading.

You have to put a pull-down resistor. That is a resistor between the input and GND. Usually 4k7 resistor is ok for that. Then when the button is released the input will sense a logic 0. This works the other way around too. You can place the button to connect to GND when pressed, and the 4k7 pull-up resistor to logic 1 (5 volt).

Furthermore, Arduino has bult-in pull up resistors for its digital input pins. Once you setup an input, you can turn the pull-up resistor with:

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT);
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
```

And then you don't need to use an actual resistor. That input will always read 1 unless you actually connect it to GND.